# Move in Word2Vec vector space in specific direction

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec

I've used gensim to train a Word2Vec model, and would like to query nearby terms. But instead of just getting the words that are closest in all directions:

```
model = models.Word2Vec.load('MyModel')        # load up my trained model
nearest = model.most_similar(['mushroom'])     # nearby words all around
```

I want to move in a particular direction and distance within the vector space and retrieve the nearest word, essentially:

```
nearest = nearest_by_vector(word, direction_vector)
```

My vector math is terrible (ie non-existent), especially with so many dimensions in my model.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is finding the vectors which are closest by distance (euclidean distance) rather than the vectors closest in angle. This is essentially the problem of [Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). The worst case/brute force searching algorithm will be linear search. But, you can google up various advanced libraries or data structures which will find these nearest neighbors in a more optimal and cost efficient manner.